# Not able to displaying properties in gephi from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I'm running the following query using `apoc.gephi.add` to display data from `Neo4j` in `Gephi`.

```
MATCH path = (pr1:Person)-[*0..2]->(pr2:Person)
WHERE pr1.id={id1} AND pr2.id={id2}  AND pr1.id<>pr2.id
CALL apoc.gephi.add ('http://localhost:8091', 'workspace', path)
YIELD nodes, relationships ,properties
RETURN *
```

In `Gephi` I'm able to see the Type of the `nodes` and `relationships`, but I'm not able to see the `properties` of the `nodes` or `properties` in `Gephi` (looking in the `Data laboratory`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

apoc.gephi.add procedure has 2 others optional parameters : weight property and properties.

The one you want is properties : it's a list of all the properties you want to give to gephi. Basically, apoc gives nothing.
you can use 'add' like this :
    CALL apoc.gephi.add ('http://localhost:8091', 'workspace', path, ['prop1','prop2'...])

More details [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_overview_of_apoc_procedures_functions).

And if you want to learn more about neo4j with gephi, [this is a good tutorial](https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/neo4j-to-gephi/), which could in addition learn you how to use weight property, a very cool feature to make relevant graphs.